# How to add more than 2 contacts for a household in npsp data import ? npsp managed package?

Tags: npsp

How to add more than 2 contacts for a household in npsp data import ? npsp managed package ?
Contact1, Contact2 and an additional contact

Comment: Are you facing any specific problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly covered in [the documentation](https://powerofus.force.com/servlet/fileField?retURL=%2Farticles%2FResource%2FNPSP-Administrators-Guide-to-Importing-Donor-Data&entityId=ka080000000Hg2WAAS&field=File__Body__s) (the parent page for this PDF is [here](https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Administrators-Guide-to-Importing-Donor-Data)):

> As part of the import process, Salesforce automatically creates a
>   Household Account for each Contact1 in the template. Later, when you
>   go to add data to the template, you can adjust the template to
>   accommodate more Household members if you have more than two people in
>   the same Household. For each new Contact in the Household, simply add
>   a new row containing Contact1 and include the new Contact in the
>   Contact2 column. Salesforce will add that new Contact (in the Contact2
>   column) to Contact1’s Household Account. You can repeat this process
>   for any additional Contacts in the Household.

Download the template, populate the data as described above, and the NPSP import process will take care of the rest for you.